# Remainder in Asymptotic Expansion of Erfc

Tags: complex-numbers, asymptotics, error-function, bounds-of-integration

According to Abramowitz and Stegun: Handbook of Mathematical Functions (7.1.23 and 7.1.24, http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_298.htm),
we have Asymptotic expansion of Erfc is given by
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\pi}z e^{z^3}\mathrm{erfcz}\sim1+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^m\frac{1.3.\cdots(2m-1)}{(2z^2)^m},\quad\left(z\mapsto\infty,\vert\mathrm{arg}z\vert<\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)
\end{align*}
The Remainder after $n$ terms is
\begin{align*}
R_{n}(z)&=(-1)^n\frac{1.3.\cdots(2n-1)}{(2z^2)^n}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}\left(1+\frac{t}{z^2}\right)^{-n-1/2}~dt.
\end{align*}
Can Any one explain, can be we get bounds of $ \vert R_{n}(z) \vert $ for complex number $z=a+ i b$ when $\frac{\pi}{2}<\mathrm{arg}(z)<\pi$?.

Comment: Where is your problem? Just set $\theta=1$ and get
$$|R_{n}(z)| = \frac{1.3.\cdots(2n-1)}{2^n|z|^{2n}}$$
For other $\arg(z)$ see http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.12.i, you have to multiply by $\csc(2|\arg (z)|).$

Comment: Why we should multiply by $\csc(2\vert \mathrm{argz}\vert )$. I searched but I could not find the answer. In my problem $\frac{\pi}{2}<\mathrm{argz}<\pi$. I want to avoid $\csc$ stuff.

Comment: The info $\frac{\pi}{2}<\mathrm{arg}(z)<\pi$  is new. DLMF writes:
*When ⁢$\pi/4≤|ph⁡z|<\pi/2$ the remainder terms are bounded in magnitude by $\csc⁡(2⁢|ph⁡z|)$ times the first neglected terms*. May be you find more in the referenced Olver book.

Comment: If you see the book Asymptotics and Special Functions by Frank Olver. Please see page 111, Equation (2.10). There are bounds for Incomplete Gamma function for $\frac{\pi}{2}<\mathrm{arg(z)}<\pi$.  What if we replace $z$ with $z^2$ and set $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: I don't know, I do not have access to the book.

Comment: @gammasester please read from here https://books.google.de/books?id=JLziBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=4+%E2%80%93+CONTOUR+INTEGRALS+F.W.J.+Olver&source=bl&ots=hFSLhyHlde&sig=H83Zzn9FflpXqK0bVcnucDcSDYY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLqIi3hq7aAhVFWxQKHQX1BtEQ6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=4%20%E2%80%93%20CONTOUR%20INTEGRALS%20F.W.J.%20Olver&f=false

Comment: I get a **Restricted Page** error, so you must help yourself. Two final comments: your formula should read $\sqrt{\pi}z e^{z^2}\mathrm{erfc}z\dots$ and IMHO you should not give a link to the complete book but only to the single page http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_298.htm.

Comment: Here is the equation referenced by @skorpion (I hope it render OK in a comment): When $\frac{1}{2}\pi \leqslant \theta \lt \pi$, we may set $\beta = \frac{1}{2}\pi$. This gives $$\lvert \varepsilon_{n}(z)\rvert \leqslant \frac{\vert (\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)\ldots(\alpha-n)\rvert}{{\lvert z \rvert}^{n}\sin \theta}\quad (n \geqslant \alpha-1, \;\;\;\tfrac{1}{2}\pi \leqslant \theta \lt \pi).\quad (2.10)$$ With $\sin \theta$ replaced by $\lvert\sin\theta\rvert$ this result also holds for $- \pi \lt \theta \leqslant -\frac{1}{2}\pi$.